# How to click in element inside a table with scroll

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a table that has a scroll, and if I want to click on an element that needs to scroll the table, selenium finds the element, does not throw any exception, but does not click on it.

```
<table class="table table-hover" fixed-header="" style="height: 175px;">
<tbody style="display: block; height: inherit; overflow: auto;">
<!-- ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="registro in calendario.meses">
<!-- end ngRepeat: registro in calendario.meses -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Given the table has the property overflow:auto, some elements are not shown.

Comment: Can you add a code sample, please? How do you try to find and click the element?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to *scroll into the view of the element*. Example in Python:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

Or, *move to the element and click* via the ["browser actions"](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains):

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, to scroll to end of the table:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var elem = document.getElementByTagName('table'); elem.scrollTop=elem.scrollHeight;");
```

if you want scroll slowly slowly then try:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var elem = document.getElementByTagName('table'); elem.scrollTop=100;");
```

Once your scroll reach to the relative element, you can perform require action.